# Проблема с Embed discord.py

Tags: discord.py

Не выводит роль, ну точнее выводит но не так как надо.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код:

```
@client.command(aliases = ['магазин']) 
async def __магазин(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(title = 'Магазин ролей')
    counter = 0
    for row in cursor.execute("SELECT role_id, cost FROM shop WHERE id = {}".format(ctx.guild.id)):
        if ctx.guild.get_role(row[0]) != None:
            counter += 1
            embed.add_field(
                name = f"№ {counter} **Роль** {ctx.guild.get_role(row[0]).mention}",
                value = f"**Стоимость** {row[1]} <:crowcoin1:870664409884803082>",
                inline = False
            )
        else:
            pass
    await ctx.send(embed = embed)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Судя по коду, python вы вообще не изучали.
2. Вопрос поставлен некорректно.
3. В документации по discord.py написано про получение объекта [`роли`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=get#discord.utils.get)
4. В параметр `name` метода `add_field` нельзя упомянуть что-либо, в `value` или `description` можно.

```py
@client.command(aliases = ['магазин']) 
async def __магазин(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(title = 'Магазин ролей')
    counter = 0
    for row in cursor.execute("SELECT role_id, cost FROM shop WHERE id = {}".format(ctx.guild.id)):
        if ctx.guild.get_role(row[0]) != None:
            counter += 1
            embed.add_field(
                name = f"№ {counter} **Роль** {(discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id=id).mention}",
                value = f"**Стоимость** {row[1]} <:crowcoin1:870664409884803082>",
                inline = False
            )
        else:
            pass
    await ctx.send(embed = embed)
```